# Can not access landing page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a basic Django application with a landing page. I did the following:

```
python manage.py startapp landing
```

Then I added `landing` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and `url(r'^$', 'landing.views.index')` to `urlpatterns`.

Inside `landing/view.py`, I added:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('landing/index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Where `landing/index.html` is my desired landing page.

When I try to access the landing page I get the error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
landing/index.html
```

What am I doing wrong?

The settings from `settings.py` are the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'landing',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learningSuite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learningSuite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Comment: Where is the index.html file?

Comment: Inside the `landing` directory.

Comment: Sorry, you need to be more specific. Directly inside the same landing directory as the model and views? Inside another landing directory inside /templates? Please show the actual directory structure.

Comment: I don't have any `templates` file. `index.html` is inside `myProject/landing`, where `myProject` is the main Django project. `settings.py` is under `myProject/myProject`.

Answer (score 2):

Templates need to go inside a separate templates directory. Either they should all be in a directory specifically named in the DIRS setting, or if APP_DIRS is True then they can be inside `<app_name>/templates`.

Comment: I moved `index.html` inside `myProject/landing/templates/`. Is there no other issue with the code I posted? I found it online and it may be from an older version of Django.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the [`APP_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-APP_DIRS) to `True` to allow Django look for templates in the `templates` directory of the project apps.

And, you need to have the `index.html` located inside `myProject/landing/templates/` directory.

Comment: It is set to `True`.

Comment: @octavian could you please post all of the template related settings? Thanks.

Comment: @octavian thanks! Added one more statement to the answer. Check it out.

Comment: I moved the file there, but I get the same issue

Comment: @octavian have you restarted the server? Also, could you post your current directory structure? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, I created a new app and then I followed this tutorial: http://grasshopperpebbles.com/django-python/how-to-set-up-a-home-page-with-django/ (I just changed the names).